# Save site as template in SharePoint Online Modern Sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-extensions, save-as-template

I want to save a SharePoint Online modern site collection as a template with SPFx application extension and want to create a SharePoint Online modern site collection using saved template.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpprovisioningtemplate?view=sharepoint-ps), however the preferred method is [Site Design](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview) scripts in addition to an external service to create the site via CSOM for what Site Designs are unable to do, for example using [Azure Functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-pnp-provisioning).

Comment: Yes, Site design is the preferred one for SharePoint Online.I want to include the my SPFX app while create a site collection. Is it possible?

Comment: If you deploy your app with the tenant wide option selected when trusting the app, yes. If not, you will need to use a CSOM method to deploy your app once the site is ready (e.g. use an Azure Function).

Comment: But here the problem is user have many customization in their site collection and SPFX app. So we cannot use site design here. we need to save like template. Is it possible to give them as a template with all those customization.

Comment: There's no easy solution. You will need to choose one of the solutions I previously mentioned.

Comment: Yes, but we should not suggest the user to run ps for create site collections. We are looking like SharePoint native(OOB) site/sitecollection creation method. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Then you want to use Site Designs which calls a Flow which calls an Azure Function. This will allow the user to use native provisioning features of the self-service UI.

Comment: Thanks. Will check and update here.